Trying to add Kotlin Run/Debug configuration in Android project. Getting Error: No main class specified
I'm trying to add Kotlin Run/Debug configuration in my Android project. I want to test a code from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#naming-coroutines-for-debugging
I want to see coroutines names in my logs, but I need to add -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug to VM options in Kotlin configuration.
I've found a solution from How to get the name of a coroutine in Kotlin? but it works only for IntelliJ.
When I'm trying to create KOtlin config studio displays Error: No main class specified.
How to add Kotlin configuration in Android Studio project?
and How to get information about coroutine in debugger?
